# Custom template for view with block display in a page

Tags: views, theming, 8, blocks

I created a template `views_block__applications_block_1.twig` for a block used on one of my pages. The block is based on a block view (unformatted list). Under blocks, the machine-readable name is `views_block__applications_block_1`. After searching around, I found that `views_block__applications_block_1.twig` should be the right template name. But no matter what I try, it doesn't seem to be working, all changes to the file are invisible. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

File content:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a view of unformatted rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - rows: A list of the view's row items.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's content.
 * - view: The view object.
 * - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be
 *   used on rows.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
 */
#}
<h1>TEST<h1>
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }} - TEST</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct naming is:

`views-view--applications--block-1.html.twig`

Also, the custom template should be based on the `views-view.html.twig` template, rather than on the `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` template.

The following are the possible template names sorted by precedence:

```
[base template name]--[view machine name]--[view display id].html.twig

[base template name]--[view machine name]--[view display type].html.twig

[base template name]--[view display type].html.twig

[base template name]--[view machine name].html.twig

[base template name].html.twig
```

(Source: http://redcrackle.com/blog/drupal-8/theme-views-templates)